# What is the correct way to include nested header files in multithreading in c

Tags: c, multithreading, include, global-variables

I have the following header and source files.

```
clnt_thread.h        included in clnt_thread.cpp and main.c
jacc_sim.h           included in jacc_sim.cpp and main.c
srvr_info.h          included in srvr_info.cpp and main.c
constants.h          included in clnt_thread.h and in srvr_info.h, both see above
                          and in global_variables.c
global_variables.h   included in main.c
main.c
```

Some variables are declared as `extern` in `clnt_thread.h` and others in `jacc_sim.h`.

My problem is, when I define the global variables as `extern` in some of the header files I get errors saying that either they are undefined or they are defined multiple times. Plus, some of the global variables are to be shared among threads while some are to be used by each thread independently.

I know these errors are a result of the way the header files are nested(included) in the source files.

So:

1. What is the correct way to include these header files and define the `extern` variables?
2. What distinguishes a variable shared among threads and another one which should not be shared between threads?

Comment: You've not shown how you think they are declared/defined in the headers.  How are we supposed to guess what you're doing?  Did you use the keyword `extern` in the headers?  If not, that's a major part of your problem.  Note that headers are a compile-time issue; multithreading is a run-time issue.  They're essentially unrelated.

Comment: Because “They're ... unrelated.”

Comment: If you are getting multiple definition errors, it probably means you forgot to use `extern`, and perhaps you are not guarding your header files from multiple inclusion.

Comment: The issue you seem to be facing is unrelated to whether the program is multi- or single-threaded.

Comment: @alk: The OP may be confused about how to declare or define thread specific variables, but that aspect was not raised in the post.

Comment: Which language are you using? The title says C, the `.cpp` extension suggests C++, both tags are present. But the two languages have (slightly) different rules.

Comment: @MSalters c++ tag added by an editor. and .cpp extension is by mistake. I am using visual studio 2015 and its default extension is .cpp. I know I am supposed to change it to .c which i will do right away.

Comment: @George: Ok, changed the tags. But please note that Visual Studio use the C++ compiler on .cpp files, unless you **explicitly** tell it not to. Just writing C code in .cpp files is **not sufficient**. And on a slightly unrelated note, C got threading in the C11 version of the language, but Microsoft only supports the much, much older C89 version. (That's 22 years older!). Visual Studio _does_ support C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Do follow these rules:

1. Do not define variables in headers, only declare them. I.e. always use `extern` with variables.
2. Define each variable (declared `extern` by 1.) exactly once in exactly one code file, i.e. without `extern`.
3. Even declaring variables should only be done once, in one header. (Though the compiler will not complain if you do it consistently, it is still much cleaner and safer to do it only once.)
4. Function prototypes go into headers, once; i.e. with `;` at the end.
5. Function definitions go into code files, once; i.e. with function head (prototype without `;`) followed by function body ( `{...}`).
6. Whatever you want to access or refer to, include the header which declares it into the file (header or code file you need it in).
7. Use reinclusion guards for extra safety (mostly for macros etc.).

Example of a reinclusion guard:

MyHeader.h:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

/* only declarations */

#endif /* MYHEADER_H */
```

Comment: This admittedly only answer "1.". I believe however (agreeing with alk) that only "1." is relevant for solving OPs problem.