# When to use #include "file.c" and when to use #include "file.h" in c

Tags: c, header-files

In what situations we need to use `.h` file and when to use the `.c` file in C.
Are they two alternatives for a same purpose?.
Please explain.

Comment: never `#include file.c`.

Comment: When to use ```#include "file.c"```? Basically never. There's a few rare edge cases, but as the saying goes, "if you have to ask..."

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50593094/2472827.

Comment: Where ever you found `#include "file.c"`, it is plain wrong with near 100% probability. You will know if you need to do it, and you will have enough experience. Until then, see it as an error. -- However, if you have a specific example that led to this question, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Never include .c files
2. If you include something, it should be a .h file.
3. Code goes into code files, .c.
4. Headers, .h files, contain only what can be compiled more than once, i.e. declarations, macro definitions, more includes.
5. If necessary, headers use reinclusion guards.

Whenever you feel tempted to include a .c file, you instead want to add it to your project so that it gets processed during building, i.e. gets compiled by its own and in a further build step gets linked into the created binary.

Comment: More on what goes where and why https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440374/7733418 (one of my other answers).